# passive form of Do you want to play?

Tags: passive-voice

I'm confused on what will be the passive form of **Do you want to play?**

I think it will be **Is hockey/football(or any other sport) intended to be played by you?**

Comment: There is no passive form.  All three verbs in this sentence are used intransitively.

Comment: There is no real sense in trying to make this question passive. It also depends whether the question is an invitation or a suggestion. Let's assume it is "Do you want to play hockey?" "Does hockey want to be played by you?" disguises the invitation and just doesn't make sense outside of very specific usage. "Should hockey be played (by us)?" is the suggestion, but again this is an unusual construction. If this is from a practice question or similar, then no wonder you are confused!

Answer (score 2):

Without object, the sentence cannot be made passive.

The idea of making anything in passive is to interchange the subject and object and thus make the sentence more meaningful or to reveal/hide the identity. Consider [these reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Reasons_for_using_the_passive_voice) for using the passive voice.

> Do you want to play? lacks *object* in that

Add some object and it'll be possible.